# Update performance issue will be addressed by creating index on where condition column

Tags: sql, indexing

I have UPDATE query in service which is causing performance issue .

If we create index on the column which are used in where condition of UPDATE statement , will be the performance issue addressed .

How valid is my question?

```
UPDATE TABLE table_name 
set description='some text',
 title='some title',
updated_ts=now() 
where some_id_col=?;
```

Comment: yes .. this is the normal behavior for index

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
update table table_name 
    set description = 'some text',
        title = 'some title',
        updated_ts = now() 
where some_id_col = ?;
```

You want an index on `some_id_col` or an index where `some_id_col` is the first key in the index.  Update statements will use indexes under these circumstances -- just be sure the parameter passed in is the same type as the column.